# How to apply color filters using FFmpegWrapper in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to apply color filters on video Using ffmpeg. Is this possible using FFmpegWrapper ?

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: @Mary I found no way to apply color filters using https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper

Comment: I guess you did the right thing [asking the developers](https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper/issues/20).